# Disable ViewRootImpl in Android Log?

Tags: android, debugging, xamarin

I just started using Xamarin. I mostly debug some little values using Console.WriteLine(). This works fine, but the ViewRootImpl Logs are really annoying. If you press a button, it shows it's current state.

```
[ViewRootImpl] ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN  
[ViewRootImpl] ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP  
[TestApp] 22  
[ViewRootImpl] ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN  
[TestApp] 23  
[ViewRootImpl] ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP  
[ViewRootImpl] ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN  
[TestApp] 24  
[ViewRootImpl] ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP
```

I hope someone can help me :3

Comment: never seen this problem, can you share your example app?

Comment: @AlexSorokoletov I don't have it anymore but thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 5):

I didn't find a setting or mode to disable the ViewRootImpl logging, but what i did discover is that's it not happening on all Android devices.

For example running the same code on a Nexus 9 with API level 22 I don't see the ViewRootImpl logging in my application output. When I run it again on a LG G4 with API level 21 I see the ViewRootImpl logging when I touch control on the screen.

What I thought that could possibly help remove this logging is setting the debug logging to Minimal/Quit in the Xamarin Studio prefences but that also didn't remove the logging.

Also on the emulator (Nexus 10 API level 19) I don't see the logging. It feels like it somehow has to do with the device your running the app on.

Probably not the answer your looking for, but hopefully it helps you in bypassing the logging when you need it by using a different device / emulator.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like something related to LG phones, I have a LG Aristo I use for testing, it has the same logs. but my emulator doesn't log it.

Answer (score 0):

Someone can try this in `Log Tag`
`^your_log_tab` in edit filter configuration